# Implementing a thread safe queue for serial data received event handler in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, queue, uart

I am sending serial data from an STM32F4-Nucleo device to a Windows Forms application which is written in C#. I am running my setup at a baud rate of 115200 and in the GUI I want to add the data to a live chart (kayChart) as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlDwVUR71yI&t=457s).

The `serialDataReceivedEventHandler` function reads the data and updates the chart:

```
private void serialDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, 
 SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string recvData = null;
    SerialPort serial = sender as SerialPort;
    try
    {
        recvData = serial.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        
    }


    // chart update
    double data;
    
    if (Double.TryParse(recvData, out data))
    {
        serialDataKayChart.TriggeredUpdate(data);
    }
}
```

I am sending an ADC sample (2 bytes) every 5ms which I assume is too fast for the chart to update since bytes are being built up in the buffer faster than they can be processed.

I have read on numerous other posts that serial port should use thread safe queue instead, but I cannot find any good resources that shows me how I would go about doing this. Could someone please help me implement this?

Comment: A thread safe queue... what about a [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) If you need to process the items coming into the queue you can use an [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) that has a built in input buffer.

Comment: @JSteward how would I implement the ConcurrentQueue for my example?

Comment: Your case is not really concurrent. It is a classic consumer-producer situation. But if your consumer is slower than your producer, any queue will eventually overflow. This is also why Observables are a better approach.  First of all it implements a performant thread safe queue, but you also get tool to filter, resample, transform your stream to become consumable. Start here: https://kerry.lothrop.de/serial-rx/